# Is there a way to intercept the request made by an iframe's src attribute?

Tags: javascript, iframe, proxy, service-worker, service-worker-events

I'm currently coding a web application, and I'm trying to educate myself on the use of **service workers**, for reasons of efficiency and resource availability.

I've seen that it's possible **to intercept most client-side requests**, and that's exactly the functionality I'm looking for.

However, my application uses **iframes** and **I can't manage to intercept the request made by the src attribute**.

Here's a POC:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/3m4lyvbs6efg8pyhv7kupo6dh">
  <title>Service Worker Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" style="width:104px;height:142px;">

  <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
  <iframe src="/index.html"></iframe>

  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
        .then(registration => {
          console.log('Service Worker registered with scope:', registration.scope);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Service Worker registration failed:', error);
        });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**sw.js**

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    console.log('Service worker, event for:', event.request.url);

    event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
});
```

**Google Chrome console**
[image]

**Results:**
We can see that requests initiated by the `script` and `img` tags **have been intercepted by the service worker**.
However, only one of the two requests initiated by the `iframe` tag was intercepted (the one whose origin is equivalent to my web application).

My aim is not to load an iframe that violates the Content Security Policy directive, but **only to intercept the request made by the src attribute**.

Thank you in advance for your help. If the service workers are not suitable for this purpose, but there are other methods, I'm open to it.

Comment: Your service worker only handles requests for the origin on which it's registered, which is why the request loading from somewhere else entirely (`www.w3schools.com` in your example) isn't intercepted. You can't intercept another site's traffic. I doubt there's anything else you can use (other than a browser extension) that can intercept that traffic.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually, I don't want to intercept requests from any other origin. I only want to intercept all requests made by my client. It doesn't matter what requests come from the iframe (scripts, png files... from w3school), I'm only looking for requests to the iframe (the src attribute here).
I thought loading an iframe from my client was like loading a resource (scripts, png files...).

Comment: *"Actually, I don't want to intercept requests from any other origin."* Then what you have is working, because you're intercepting one of the requests (which is to your origin) and not the other (which is to another origin). *"I thought loading an iframe from my client was like loading a resource..."* I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. When you load an iframe using `src="https://www.w3schools.com"`, you're creating an `iframe` in your page with content loaded from **their** origin. The only network operation involved related to the `iframe` is a GET to their origin.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I better understand, thank you very much. My goal is to catch the request made by the iframe then. I would like to get in my chrome console something like : 
`Service worker, event for https://www.w3schools.com`
Like the other logs generated by the service worker. My goal is just to catch this GET request (https://www.w3schools.com) from the client side, but idk how to do it.

Comment: As far as I know, except in a browser extension, you can't. :-|